# JBL 500BT bluetooth headset, Unable to keep connection

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

I have a JBL 500BT bluetooth headset. When I try to connect it to Ubuntu, it connects for 3 seconds, disconnects, and then stops being detected.

I tried to use `blueman`, but it fails to pair. I tried to install `bluez` and `pulseaudio` but it's still the same. I also tried `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` but it fails to connect.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Any ideas?

Comment: the title of your post does not match the content ... the headset would not connect at all if it was not being detected

Comment: That's because it detects, connect for a few seconds and stop being detected, sorry

Comment: Try`bluetoothctl` , In the program enter `disconnect <MAC>` and then `connect <MAC>` (Where `<MAC>` is the mac-address of the hadset. It likely also have two modes, one for High Fidelity Playback and one as Headset (use mic). You can set this by `bluetoothctl` as well - but might find it easier to use `pavucontrol`, tab `Configuration` (which is way better then the bundled audio control imo).

Comment: @ibuprofen it throws the error `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed` when I try to connect

Comment: Does `systemctl status bluetooth.service` yield anything useful after that?

Comment: Also try to start pulseaudio as root.

Comment: @ibuprofen `systemctl status bluetooth.service` gives me 
`jun 17 15:52:16 canoafurada bluetoothd[5958]: L2CAP server failed for File Tran>
jun 17 15:52:16 canoafurada bluetoothd[5958]: L2CAP server failed for Object Pu>
jun 17 15:53:58 canoafurada bluetoothd[5958]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed >
` the last line is repeated 7 more times

Comment: I ran
`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
`sudo killall pulseaudio`
`pulseaudio --start`    
`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
and it's now everything working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran
`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
`sudo killall pulseaudio`
`pulseaudio --start`
`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
and now everyting is working fine